# apt-get does not seem to be reading /var/cache/apt/archives

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am trying to upgrade Ubuntu in stages, I want to first download all the required packages and only then start the upgrade.

So, I downloaded required debian packages
and copied them to `/var/cache/apt/archives` (before doing a `dist-upgrade`). But still, I see that `apt` tries to `Get:` (download) the packages.

If the cache were hit, it should have shown `Hit:` correct ? Is there any way to know
if `apt` is looking for packages in some other location ? Also, is there an option to *force*
`apt` to *always* look in the cache before trying to download?

Comment: I am not using `rsync` here. I just download the required packages on another machine and copy it to the one to be upgraded (and place them in `/var/cache/apt/archives`).

Comment: @vyom that IS the point. You are using a standard tool to copy, but anx believes the timestamps matter, so you might NEED to use rsync. I would be tempted to try using rsync, I don't know if timestamps matter.

Comment: There are other things that could have gone wrong.. such as missing dependencies or mismatched versions in the files you downloaded. The output with `--dry-run` might tell..

Comment: if you prefer to download why not install `apt-cacher-ng` on that machine and use it as proxy?

Comment: ok, I will try `dry-run`

Comment: Please include the output from `apt dist-upgrade` and `ls -al /var/cache/apt/archives`

Comment: Due to some environment settings, `apt` was looking under `/var/cache/apt/archives/archives`! A subdirectory under archives! I've resolved it now. Thank you all for suggestions.

Comment: @vyom If your problem is solved, please write an answer (not just a comment). On this site, you can and are in fact encouraged to also mark your own answers as "accepted" if they were the most useful.

Comment: FWIW, you can also use `apt -d upgrade` to perform the download only.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some environment settings, `apt` was looking under `/var/cache/apt/archives/archives` !
(a subdirectory under `archives`)
I had to reset the environment, and then it worked. Thank you all for suggestions.